# how to count the total number of documents that have more than one object in an Elasticsearch field array?

Tags: elasticsearch

The structure of the documents in my index is similar to:

```json
{
  "_index": "blabla",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_source": {
    "uid": 5366492,
    "aField": "Hildegard",
    "aNestedField": [{
        "prop": {
          "data": "xxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      {
        "prop": {
          "data": "yyyyyyyy"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to have the total number of documents in the whole index that have more than one object in the `aNestedField` field. So, the above one will be counted, because it has 2.

If my index has 100 documents, and the above one is the only one with more than 2 objects in that field, I would expect to have my query to return 1.

Is there a way of doing it?

---

Updated after having read the comments.

The mapping for the field is:

```json
{
  "aNestedField": {
    "properties": {
      "prop": {
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data will not be updated often, no need to worry about it.

Comment: Is `aNestedField` strictly of the ES `nested` data type or are you using that term loosely? Also, will it be frequently updated down the line or rather not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `prop.data` field is not being indexed (`"index": false`), you'll need at least one field inside of each `aNestedField` object that **is** being indexed -- either by explicitly setting `"index": true` or by *not* setting `"index": false` in its mapping.

Your docs should then look something like this:

```
{
  "uid": 5366492,
  "aField": "Hildegard",
  "aNestedField": [
    {
      "id": 1,    <--
      "prop": {
        "data": "xxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,    <--
      "prop": {
        "data": "yyyyyyyy"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 3,    <--
      "prop": {
        "data": "yyyyyyyy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*`id` is arbitrary -- use anything that makes sense.*

After that you'll be able to query for docs with more than 2 array objects using:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['aNestedField.id'].size() > 2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Joe, I managed to have the query to work, but I made some modification. I changed the mapping to: ```json {
  "...
          "data": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false,
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "doc_values": true,
                    "index": false
                  }...
``` and in this way it was not necessary to add a new field. Consequently, there is another level in the object nesting, `aNestedField.prop.data`. If you amend your reply, I will accept it.

Comment: Yea well your addition does not really contribute to the solution b/c ES will deduplicate the values and you won't get the counts you expect (in the worst case). So I'd suggest a numeric field instead.